# How to clear animation applied to ImageView android using startAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have applied a zoom in animation to my `Imageview` using

```
myImageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.zoom_in ));
```

by specifying `android:fillEnabled` and `android:fillAfter` attributes of animation to true.How can I , at a later point of time clear the animation and revert my `ImageView` to the old state?I Tried with `clearAnimation()` method of `ImageView` but seems not to be working with `fillEnabled` and `fillAfter` attributes .

Answer (score 7):

```
myImageView.setAnimation(null);
```

should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: no it seems..i tried with that too..infact what i want is to cancel a previously set animation at a later point of time

Answer (score 1):

`myImageView.clearAnimation()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
yourAnimation.cancel();
```